# Assembly references broken when compiled with msbuild (CLI)

Tags: unity-game-engine, msbuild, mono

## background

My overall Goal is to get Sonarqube running in a CI for a Unity Project.
From what I understand, to get sonar scanner to work, I have to compile the projects I want analyzed with msbuild outside of unity.
I built an ubuntu based docker image that contains Unity, monodevel and sonarscanner.
The ci runs a shell script containing lines:

```bash
mono /opt/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin \ #...more arguments
msbuild Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj
mono /opt/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end -d:sonar.login="$SONAR_TOKEN"
```

While the solution compiles flawlessly in Unity, the msbuild step fails with compiler errors like `cs0246` and `cs0234`. Glancing at the errors, they all appear to originate from references across assemblys.

## Minimal example:

I have created 2 assemblies `A` and `B` in Unity.
`A` doesn't depend on anything and `B` just depends on `A`. Unity creates the .csproj files `A.csproj` and `B.csproj`.
Both assemblies contain a single static class each:

```C#
public static class A {
    public static void TestA() => Console.WriteLine("Testing A");
}
```

```C#
public static class B {
    public static void TestB() => A.TestA(); 
}
```

When I run

```
msbuild B.csproj
```

Clearly the dependency is picked up by, as near the start of the log there is

> Project "/builds/root/logoleon-app/B.csproj" (1) is building
> "/builds/root/logoleon-app/A.csproj" (2:2) on node 1 (default
> targets).

After succeeding to build the `A` assembly

> Done Building Project "/builds/root/logoleon-app/A.csproj" (default
> targets).

it moves on to `B` but fails with

> Assets/test/B/B.cs(3,9): error CS0103: The name 'A' does not exist in
> the current context [/builds/root/logoleon-app/B.csproj]

Complete end of the log file starting with the `msbuild B.csproj` command: https://pastebin.com/mdBdPTrJ including contents of `A.csproj` and `B.csproj`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was, that, while Unity 2020.3.1f1 generates Project references in the .csproj, they contain

```xml
<ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
```

Theres a [fix by user Kichang-Kim on the Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/2019-3-12f1-build-errors.880312/#post-5789368) Build Errors that helps.
(modified using c#6 expression body)

```c#
using UnityEditor;
public class SolutionFileFixer : AssetPostprocessor
{
    private static string OnGeneratedCSProject(string path, string content) => content.Replace(
        "<ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>",
        "<ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>");
}
```

I do not yet know in which unity versions - or if at all - this is fixxed.